# Migration from Oracle to CDS using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, cds

I am trying to migrate data from Oracle to an entity in Common Data Service( CDS) through Azure Data Factory Copy Activity. As CDS comes with GUID as a primary key and Oracle doesnt have primary key, my pipeline always fails.

I tried to create an additional column in source data set with value as @guid() however it throws that column  must be of type guid

also tried
select REGEXP_REPLACE(SYS_GUID(), '(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') MSSQL_GUID,c. * from table_name c;
guid is coming as string in the mapping

How do we automatically generate guid in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try updating your additional column (@guid()) data type from "type": "String" to "type": "Guid" by editing the JSON payload of your pipeline (look for {} symbol at top right corner of your pipeline). See below GIF:

[image]

**Update**:

After further analysis by collaborating with product team, it (type coversion) is identified as an unsupported feature with dynamics sink, where UX disables type conversion for dynamics sink. UX hasn't supported it since the release of type conversion feature.

Product team has opened a work item as a feature improvement for type conversion with Dynamics sink . The ETA for this feature support is mid of September (*Note: This is tentative date*), but product team is actively working on it. I will closely monitor the work item and will update this post as soon as I have additional information.

As a workaround, please try to split pipeline into 2 copies (copy activities). Oracle -> csv & csv -> dynamics. In first copy, add an additional column to write empty guid column in csv file. In second copy, change the type of guid column in csv to Guid and do the copy.

Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Kranthi,

Thanks for the update.

I did split the migration process in to 2 pipelines( 1 from oracle to sql server and other from sql to CDS). Oracle to SQL server performance is at its best, however performance from sql server to CDS needs lot of improvement.


For example if the copy of data around 75 MB takes 2 min in first pipeline, it took around 1 hour 15 mins in the second pipeline.

We have hosted Integration run time on the SQL server Azure VM itself. We tried Setting degree of parallelism to 9 too. 
Could you recommend any performance improvement techniques here